# Drawing a Pie Chart on Google Glass

Tags: android, charts, google-glass

I'm trying to create an app that takes random numbers from a random number generator and draws a pie chart using those numbers and displays it on the card on Glass. However since it must be done in java, javascript or HTML charts won't work.

Any suggestions about how to go about doing this? I've been looking into achartengine but android studio isn't recognizing the library.

Comment: What about Google Charts API? https://developers.google.com/chart/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from achart engine there are two good android libraries used to draw pie chart. You can download and refer those in your app project to see if they are recognized by Android Studio. Since Google Glass is a relatively new platform for app development, developers have to figure out on their own which combination fits the process.

Here are the links, [this](http://androidplot.com/download/) and [this](http://www.android-graphview.org/download--getting-started.html).

Hope this would help!!!